# Weblogic Blocking threads caused application unresponsive

Tags: multithreading, oracle, weblogic, blocked

We are facing issue in our production environment with multiple blocking threads and while checking the thread dumps have found the below stack trace where in 14 blocking threads were present with same description. Any help with the below is much appreciated.

We are using weblogic 10.3.6.0 version and JDK 1.7.0_80.

**ExecuteThread: '387' is blocked because ExecuteThread: '159' is already holding the lock and is long-running.**

======================

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '387' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002ac72d4f4000 nid=0x530d waiting for monitor entry [0x00002ac767c38000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1030)
- waiting to lock <0x000000051ea30728> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1013)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:999)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:433)
```

### ..

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '159' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002ac7491f5800 nid=0x4781 runnable [0x00002ac7540fd000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1030)
- locked <0x000000051ea30728> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1013)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:999)
..
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:151)
```

---

```
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '359' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '359' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 
Stack Trace is: 
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2818)
- locked <0x0000000566efc058> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1215)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getString(Unknown Source)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.type.StringTypeHandler.getResult(StringTypeHandler.java:35)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.ResultMap.getPrimitiveResultMappingValue(ResultMap.java:619)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.ResultMap.getResults(ResultMap.java:345)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.AutoResultMap.getResults(AutoResultMap.java:47)
- locked <0x00000005205e0968> (a com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.AutoResultMap)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleResults(SqlExecutor.java:384)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleMultipleResults(SqlExecutor.java:300)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:189)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(MappedStatement.java:221)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:189)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:139)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:298)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:209)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:249)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:296)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:290)
at com.dms.common.masters.daos.HomeDaoImpl.populateDropDowns(Unknown Source)
at com.dms.common.masters.daos.HomeDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$dda6d555.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:696)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:631)
at com.dms.common.masters.daos.HomeDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7cce49ec.populateDropDowns(<generated>)
at com.dms.common.masters.business.HomeBusinessImpl.populateDropDowns(Unknown Source)
at com.dms.common.masters.service.HomeServiceImpl.populateDropDowns(Unknown Source)
at com.dms.common.masters.action.HomeAction.menu(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54415.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.utils.LoginInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at com.utils.SetResponseBufferFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1499)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

Comment: this stack does not show a "blocked" thread as you say. It is running, may be very slowly but it is running. On the other hand it seems your weblogic server is running a very high number of execute threads, between 350 and 400. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply when i try to analyse the thread dumps i have found multiple blocking threads. Sorry for the ignorance care to explain how do i check the execute thread count.

Comment: Can you share stack traces from "blocked" threads ? The execute thread has an ID of 359. WebLogic starts at 1 and can create up to 400 threads by default.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Have updated the post with the updated thread stack also i have checked the thread dumps using fastthread.io and shows that more thank 40% of threads were in blocked state.

Answer (score 0):

Blocked threads are not necessarily a concern, in java when handling concurrent requests and using singleton classes or hashmaps etc its natural to have some blocking as a means to achieve sanity in data...
When to take thread dumps -
When weblogic server is reporting stuck threads, or you are getting general slowness in response (though many other factors contribute to this)

How to take thread dumps -
Always take 3-4 thread dumps spaced 1-2 secs apart. Looking at 1 momentary thread dump usually does not provide the complete picture.. If you notice the same threads are in blocked state in almost all 3-4 dumps, check which thread is holding the lock and what it is doing, is the thread holding the lock doing the same task in all 4 dumps, if so you got the clue on what to troubleshoot..

In the thread dump you gave..

ExecuteThread: '387' is waiting on 
waiting to lock <0x000000051ea30728>

and ExecuteThread: '159' is holding locked <0x000000051ea30728> but 159 is in Runnable state, meaning its not stuck and doing its normal operations..

had you taken several thread dumps and saw 159 holding the lock for far too long you need to consider tuning your application and think about a workaround if possible around this lock.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the lock on `com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.AutoResultMap`
suggesting that part of the code is synchronized, meaning that ONLY one thread at a time will be executed.

If you collect a thread dump, you'll see several threads are waiting for the lock and only one is executing something like:

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '339' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=REMOVED nid=REMOVED runnable [REMOVED]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.wasNull(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.type.StringTypeHandler.getResult(StringTypeHandler.java:36)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.ResultMap.getPrimitiveResultMappingValue(ResultMap.java:619)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.ResultMap.getResults(ResultMap.java:345)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.AutoResultMap.getResults(AutoResultMap.java:47)
    - locked <0x00000004544b7328> (a com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.AutoResultMap)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleResults(SqlExecutor.java:384)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleMultipleResults(SqlExecutor.java:300)
```

...

That leads us to another question, does IBatis support multithread? Based on the following link the answer is no:

**Mybatis does not work in multithreaded programming**

*In standard usage of MyBatis core module, the SqlSession and mapper object does not support the thread-safe. This is design. The MyBatis provide the SqlSessionManager for supporting the thread-safe as optional component.*

https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1529